# How to turn a program that prints an array backwards into a recursive one that prints the Nth character?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm having trouble transitioning this program into a recursive one. My function will also have to write the Nth character of the array, supplied as a parameter.

I'm to constrain N to be 1 <= N <= 3 as well.

If someone were to explain why my professor included the 
'cout << ends;' as well. 
Thanks.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring> 
 namespace std;


 // print an array backwards, where 'first' is the first index
 // of the array, and 'last' is the last index 
 void writeArrayNthBackward(const char anArray[], int first, int last, int n) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = last; i >= first; i--) {
    std::cout << anArray[i];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// test driver
int main() {
  const char *s = "abc123";
  writeArrayNthBackward(s, 0, strlen(s) - 1, 1 <= n <= 3);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a homework question  :)

Comment: `std::cout << std::endl;` writes a newline into the stream, and then flushes the stream. The flush is expensive, so you really only want to use `endl` when you absolutely have to. Use `std::cout << '\n';` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code looks wrong I think the right one is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
 namespace std;


 // print an array backwards, where 'first' is the first index
 // of the array, and 'last' is the last index 
 void writeArrayNthBackward(const char anArray[], int first, int last, int n) {
  for (int i = last; i >= first; i--) {
    std::cout << anArray[i];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// test driver
int main() {
  const char *s = "abc123";
  writeArrayNthBackward(s, 0, strlen(s) - 1, 1 <= n <= 3);
}
```

And if you want to make it recursive you can use this:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cstring> 
 namespace std;


 // print an array backwards, where 'first' is the first index
 // of the array, and 'last' is the last index 
 void writeArrayNthBackwardRec(const char anArray[], int index, int n) {
  if (index == n) {
    std::cout << anArray[index];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  if (index != 0) {
     writeArrayNthBackwardRec(anArray, --index, n);
  }
}

// test driver
int main() {
  const char *s = "abc123";
  if (n >= 1 && n <= 3) {
     writeArrayNthBackwardRec(s, strlen(s) - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a very smart way to print the nth element of an array because you have direct access to it.

But if you were to do it this way, the best way to do this is to write another function to help the main one out by adding an additional parameter that keeps track of the current index. Use the nth value you've been passed in originally as the base case, and recurse until you've reached the base case. Start from the back of the array and test your code to make sure you have all the right checks.

The std::cout << std::endl is to print a new line.